# Copy every other value from a column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have the below sample data set with values in `Column B` .

In `Column D` I want every other value, starting at `Row 1`.

```
0   A   B   C   D   F   G   H   I   J
1       20     =B1
2       10     =B3
3       30     =B5
4       8      =B7
5       9      =B9
6       4      etc.
7       79
8       67
9       63
10      45
```

How can I do this with fill handle or a Formula ?

Answer (score 5):

You need to use a formula:

`=INDIRECT("B"&INT(ROW()*2)-1)`

Comment: It should be `(ROW()*2)-1)`

Answer (score 4):

In Cell D2 you can use the below formula, then drag down:

```
=INDEX(B:B,(ROWS($B$1:B1)*2)-1,1)
```

Answer (score 3):

[image]

**Edited:**

Write this formula in Cell `D1` & fill down:

```
=INDEX(B:B,1+(2*ROW()-2))
```

**Note,**

- If you want even row sequence like `10, 8, 4, 67` then write following formulain `D1` & fill down.

  `=INDEX(B:B,1+(2*ROW()-1))`
- Adjust cell references in formula as needed.

Comment: Please see the example data and provide a solution implementing that.

Comment: Thanks @MátéJuhász, I got confused that OP is looking for Value from ODD & EVEN rows only so that ignored the Blanks, now edited the answer & values are in sequence.